# snap install / refresh fc-cache: No such file or directory

Tags: 20.04, snap, chromium

Im running Ubuntu 20.04 and snap suddenly stopped working. When i try to install or refresh (some) snaps like chromium or signal-desktop for example i run into the following error:

```
~/Downloads$ snap refresh chromium
Fehler: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Den Konfigurationshook von Snap "chromium" ausführen, falls vorhanden (run hook "configure": /snap/chromium/1479/snap/command-chain/hooks-configure-desktop: line 43: /snap/chromium/1479/gnome-platform/usr/bin/fc-cache: No such file or directory)


~/Downloads$ sudo snap install signal-desktop
[sudo] Passwort für marius: 
Fehler: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Den Konfigurationshook von Snap "signal-desktop" ausführen, falls vorhanden (run hook "configure": /snap/signal-desktop/346/snap/command-chain/hooks-configure-desktop: line 43: /snap/signal-desktop/346/gnome-platform/usr/bin/fc-cache: No such file or directory)
```

I already tried to remove all font cache files and rebuild with `fc-cache -f -v` but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced the exactly same issue with `chromium` snap and found that in my case it was caused by having `gnome-3-28-1804` snap installed, but disabled. I'd newer version `gnome-3-34-1804` of the `gnome-3` snap installed, but the `chromium` package apparently depends on the older version containing the `fc-cache`

After enabling the `3.28` version of the snap using `snap enable gnome-3-28-1804` I'm now able install/update the `chromium` snap.

So i recommend:

- check list of installed snaps: `snap list`
- install & enable the `gnome-3-28-1804` snap:

  - `snap install gnome-3-28-1804`
  - `snap enable gnome-3-28-1804`
- install/update `chromium` snap: `snap install chromium`

Additional notes:

- yes, `-1804` version of the `gnome-3` are installed even on Ubuntu `20.04` OS
- check also [#1915712 bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1915712) for the `chromium-browser` package in Ubuntu
- another [related `chromium` snap issue](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/default-chromium-fonts-are-missing-after-snapd-has-been-updated/21651/18) related to the `fc-cache`

Comment: Thank you so much this solved my issues.